# mysql update from form error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

The database won't update. What is the problem? I tried in many ways, all failed. I read the mysqli dictionary, the code should be working but it's not.

This is edit.php

```html
<?php require_once 'header.php' ?>
<?php 
 $id = $_GET['id'];
?>
<div class="container">
 
 <form method="post" <?php echo "action='edit_resultu.php?id=".$id."'"; ?>>

 <input type="text" name="track" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter track" maxlength="70"/>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" name="update">Submit</button>
 </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is edit_resultu.php

```html
<?php

if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
$id = $_GET['id'];
$track = $_POST['track'];

$query = "UPDATE `db71038521`.`packs` SET track = `$track` WHERE `packs`.`id` = '$id'";

if(!mysqli_query($conn, $query))
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysqli_error($query));
}
echo "Updated data successfully\n";

}


?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS) User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: Your form method is Post, you can make the id hidden field and use $_POST

Comment: This code should generate the error *Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given*. Does it? Have you ensured that PHP is configured to show you errors?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile — Using a form with `method="post"` does not prevent you from putting data in the query string and reading it in `$_GET`.

Comment: @Quentin i did not say it does, its just a bad idea to do and u knw that too

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile — It isn't a bad idea.

Comment: Besides the obvious that you should use `$conn->escape_string($yourString);` before entering the data into the database, this question does not contain enough information to solve the problem.

Comment: @PHPglue — Bound variables are a better approach than explicit escaping.

Comment: turned on the mysqli_error in php.ini. got this errors

Comment: Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in edit_resultu.php on line 10

Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in edit_resultu.php on line 12

Comment: `<?php echo "action='edit_resultu.php?id=".$id."'"; ?>` that's invalid for one thing and where is your connection codes?

Comment: `mysqli_error($query)` that's the wrong variable; you need to use the connection and not the result set.

Comment: @Fred-ii- — What's invalid about that echo statement?

Comment: @Quentin Ok "invalid" was the wrong word, more like "why use that method" ;-) This question doesn't seem to be going anywhere now, so I don't know why you're still sticking around *lol!* - P.s.: Not my downvote you got for your answer btw. Bit of a rabbit hole, wouldn't you say?

Comment: *"This is edit.php"* - you should be getting an undefined error here for the first opening lines.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> mysqli_query($conn, $query)
> ```

You are passing the variable `$conn` to `mysqli_query`… but you never assign it a value.

You need to call `mysqli_connect` to establish a connection to the database before you can query it.

> ```
> mysqli_error($query)
> ```

The point of `mysqli_error` is to ask the database server what went wrong, not to analyse a string of SQL.

You need to pass the connection (as above), not the query.

Comment: it is assigned in dbconfig.php file.

Comment: it works selecting data from database, deleting it. But not updating...

Comment: @antuanjoh — There is no mention of that file in your question. You have not shown that file's contents in the question. You have no `include` statement referencing it in the question. **The error message says that the value of `$conn` is `null`.**

Comment: @antuanjoh — Presumably, therefore, the cause of your problem is that "You forgot to include that file in `edit_resultu.php`".